# Не могу подключиться к SOAP серверу

Tags: php, https, 1с, soap

У меня есть 2 сервиса, первый - база 1с, опубликованная в Интернете, ssl куплен и установлен, второй это сайт на хостинге REG.ru (тоже на ssl). Если я делаю SOAP запрос к веб-сервису 1с (api) в локальной сети, где с обоих сторон http, то все отвечает прекрасно. Проделывая тоже самое с хостинга на опубликованную в интернете базу, выдает ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'ссылка' : failed to load external entity "ссылка" in /var/www/u0870440/data/www/ссылка/api/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/u0870440/data/www/ссылка/api/index.php(21): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://xn--80a...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/u0870440/data/www/ссылка/api/index.php on line 21` (ссылки не могу показать - база рабочая). Причем wsdl открывается в браузере. Делая запрос через SoapUI столкнулся с тем, что он не делает запрос на кириллические URL (у меня такой), может быть проблема в этом? Читал аналогичные форумы, говорят проверить extension=php_openssl.dll в php.ini, но на хостинге он не может быть отключен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);` перед инициализацией SoapClient.

Comment: ИМХО с 1с проще работать через HTTP-сервисы. они проще и удобнее, запрос можно хоть с контроллера посылать, хоть с андроида. а соап в 1с кривоват, он хорошо работает только с 1с, и то не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось все вставкой дополнительных опций в SoapClient ( [https://qna.habr.com/q/346401][1] )

```
"soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
"stream_context" => stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer'       => false,
            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        ]
    ]
)
```

Может быть кому-то пригодится.
[1]: https://qna.habr.com/q/346401